# App shortcut disappears after every update, what's wrong with my Manifest?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've no idea why this is happening, I've tried everything. Every time I update the app, the previous shortcut that was on the home screen disappears.

Here is my complete app manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.SpaceMonkey.Boats" android:versionCode="161" android:versionName="1.6.1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <application android:label="Boats" android:icon="@drawable/playstore"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

And my main activity:

```
[Activity (Label = "Boats", Icon = "@drawable/playstore", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```

The only thing I change when I update is the versionCode and versionName in the manifest, absolutely nothing else changes.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I'm starting to think that it's a problem with Xamarin generating a new app manifest in the background, I'm not sure how to check that.

EDIT: **I've just tested with an Android (Xamarin) app that doesn't use Xamarin.Forms and it didn't have that problem. My suspicions where confirmed that it's something related to Xamarin.Forms.**

Comment: what do you mean by 'update' ? from the store onto a device or everytime you launch it in debug mode or something ?

Comment: change app version and release an update. So, from the play store or just any install of a new version, I'm not talking about debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Xamarin Studio. I basically recreated the solution and copied everything, then the problem disappeared...

I don't know what was happening, but it's solved now.

Comment: Does your Version control shows you what the difference was? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I've tried creating a new project too but issue will still happen if you change the `AssemblyVersion` (as explained in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42156813/2003763 )

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was triggered by changing the `AssemblyVersion` of the `AssemblyInfo.cs` of my Android app project.

This issue is caused by Xamarin.Android 5.0 and later (not by Xamarin.Forms). As explained [in the release documentation here](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.0/#Android_Callable_Wrapper_Naming):

> With the 5.0 release, the default package names for Android Callable
>   Wrappers will be based on the MD5SUM of the **assembly-qualified
>   name** of the type being exported.

The `AssemblyVersion` being part of the **assembly-qualified name**, any version change created a new MD5 hash, creating a new default package name. (Read more about [the assembly qualified named here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1))

App shortcut uses the default package name to launch your app so every update would make the shortcut void and the system would remove it.

**Fix:** Don't change the `AssemblyVersion` in your Android project or anything else that changes the assembly qualified name.